# hector_mapping map overlap

Tags: navigation, mapping, hector-mapping, hector

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I am doing hector mapping using a hokuyo URG-04LX ,i hold the  hokuyo in hand,moving it slowly ,but the mapping result is not very good,it is not accurate and clear,always overlaps. My launch file is following the mapping_default.launch which is inside the hector mapping.And i use only hokuyo_node and hector_mapping node .the tf seems to be ok,the tf tree is :

1. -/base_link → /laser
2. -/map → /scanmatcher_frame

Is there any way to solve the problem?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/59536/hector_mapping-map-overlap/) by [elva](https://answers.ros.org/users/4431/elva/) on ROS Answers with karma: 1 on 2013-03-29

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

The URG-04LX has pretty low range and low scan rate, so fast movements and environments with few features (in range) present difficulties. As you don't appear to use an IMU, it is also important to always keep the sensor's scan plane parallel to the ground plane at all times.

---

Originally posted by [Stefan Kohlbrecher](https://answers.ros.org/users/57/stefan-kohlbrecher/) with karma: 24361 on 2013-03-29

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [elva](https://answers.ros.org/users/4431/elva/) on 2013-03-29**:
thank you for your reply^^i have an microstrain imu, is it correct that i add hector_imu_attitude_to_tf _node and microstrain_3dmgx2_node into my launch file? In addition, I found a video which perform what i want to do ,http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=quqF5_ZE_fI,he also use 5.6m 10hz 2D lidar.

**Comment by [elva](https://answers.ros.org/users/4431/elva/) on 2013-03-29**:
May i know how the tf works?when i added imu and hector_imu_attitude_to_tf ,besides the previous 2 tf there is one more tf : 3. -/base_stabilized  → /lase_footprint. but there is warning: no transform from base_footprint to map and No transform from [/base_stabilized] to frame [/map].how to fix it?

**Comment by [jodafo](https://answers.ros.org/users/1732/jodafo/) on 2013-04-01**:
concerning the youtube video: keep in mind that it shows simulation. If you take a look at the real robot videos you can see that the map looks much worse on a real robot. Furthermore the videos don't show vanilla hector slam, but some modified version, i.e. scan matching with a 3D not 2D map.

**Comment by [elva](https://answers.ros.org/users/4431/elva/) on 2013-04-02**:
I am doing a project quite similar to that video in real world, i have a hokuyo(URG-04LX),on which there is a mirror for height estimation, i also have a imu(3DM-GX3-25) attached to my hokuyo,since  i want to apply themon a quadrotor  to do 2.5 mapping using octomap sever.but the 2D map overlaps.